# ggplot density function not correct (normal percent from Stata)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, stata

I am trying to replicate the hist normal percent. The problem is that the density plot (or normal distribution) is completely off:

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
a <- data.frame(rnorm(100,0,1))
colnames(a) <- c("test")
ggplot(a,aes(test)) +
geom_histogram(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))) +  
scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
stat_function(fun='dnorm')
```

[image: Photo]

The line should be much closer to the graph, but instead it is scaled by a factor of about 10.

Comment: In Stata, `sysuse auto, clear` followed by `hist mpg, normal percent` might be an example of what you are trying to emulate.Even though the Stata syntax isn't a guide to an R equivalent, giving a Stata example and above all showing a sample graph is crucial to a clear question.  In that case, Stata uses a percent scale for bin relative frequency and superimposes a normal distribution (with same mean and SD) scaled to the same units.

Answer (score 3):

Not familiar with that command from Stata, but is this what you want? Density with bar height scaled so that the total area integrates to 1, like the normal curve you showed. The reason your attempt doesn't work is because you didn't account for the bin width; each bin contributes area of the width times the count. You can do this manually if you set the bin width, or you can just use the computed `..density..` variable.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(12345)
a <- data.frame(test = rnorm(100, 0, 1))
ggplot(a, aes(x = test)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count.. / (sum(..count..) * 0.2)), binwidth = 0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  stat_function(fun = "dnorm")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(a, aes(x = test)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = 0.2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  stat_function(fun = "dnorm")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).